# Php know if a user has read the message sent and also get all unread messages

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a live chat with web sockets and storing messages in a MySQL database

The following is my database structure

**`tbl_messages`**:

```
id
message
sent_by
sent_on
```

another table for the relation which is useful in case user deletes a message to only delete his relation

**`tbl_message_users`**:

```
message_id
user_id
read // 0 or 1
```

The `read` above defaults to 0 (not read) for the user to which messages are being sent to.

Now in my web sockets after a user clicks a send button a send-message event is triggered in nodejs which executes a function to retrieve messages again for updates.

What am not sure on how to implement unread messages. Suppose a user is offline I would like him to get a notification on unread messages that are the messages with `read=0`.

Suppose also a user is logged in but hasn't opened the chat box also that becomes an unread message.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score -3):

Sorry boy but I don't understand where You find the problem... It's really simple

---

**Case 1 :** Offline user notification  (Server-Side)

When user login into chat service You need to do a query in "tbl_messages_users" with param "read = 0". Then You have to stylize the DB's output

```
/** I'm using PHP syntax because I'm not good with NodeJS **/

$query = new Query(...);
$results = $query->getResults();
if(count($results) > 0) {
    foreach($results as $result) {
        /** .... STYLISH THIS (Ex. in HTML) .... **/
    }
}
```

> **How to use trick?** When Server generate page for User (Server-Side)

---

**Case 2 :** Online user (Client-Sider)

```
/** I'm using jQuery syntax **/

/**
* %HTTP_METHOD%                   :    GET or POST ?
* %SERVER_SIDE_URL%               :    Where is the action?
* %DATA_TO_SERVER_SIDE_ACTION%    :    Example ClientID
*
* We use JSON Data Object because is really simple to parse in jQuery
**/
$.ajax({
    type: "%HTTP_METHOD%",
    url: "%SERVER_SIDE_URL%",
    data: "%DATA_TO_SERVER_SIDE_ACTION%"
}).done(function(json) {
    /** indexOf prevent invalid HTML characters **/
    json = json.substring(json.indexOf("{")); 
    json = $.parseJSON(json);

    /** Create Your JSON Data Structure, iterate It and generate HTML to append in notification panel **/

}).fail(function(httpResponse) {
   /** 
   * Stylish an HTML exception 
   * httpResponse    :    Contains Server HTTP response data (Ex. response code like 200, ..., 500) 
   **/
});
```

How to call Ajax Request?

```
setTimeout(function() {
   myAjaxRequest( ...params ):
}, %EVERY_X_MILLISECONDS%);
```

OR USE TRIGGER

```
$(document).on("%MY_TRIGGER%", myCallbackFunction);

function myCallbackFunction(e) {
    myAjaxRequest( ...params ):
}
```

> **How to use trick?** When User calls a Server API (Client-Side)

---

**Combine Case 1 with Case 2**

In %SERVER_SIDE_URL% (Case 2) You can put a URL that return JSON Data Object

```
/** I'm using PHP syntax because I'm not good with NodeJS **/

$query = new Query(...);
$results = $query->getResults();
$RESULT = array();
if(count($results) > 0) {
    $RESULT['status'] = 'OK';
    $RESULT['unreadMessages'] = array();
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $RESULT['unreadMessages'][] = array(
            'message' => $result->message,
            'date' => $result->messageDate,
            /** ... etc **/
        );
    }
} else { 
    $RESULT = array(
        'status' => 'KO',
        'error' => 'No unread messages for user %USER_ID%',
    );
}

echo json_encode($RESULT);
exit; /** PREVENT SCRIPT TO REMAIN ALIVE IN BACKGROUND **/
```

AFTER

> Call the Server Page through Ajax Request (See in Case 2)

---

## Conclusion

You can use Case 2 when User login into chat system or if User is also into chat system. Just launch the jQuery trigger when You want!! =)